# Dejar obligatorio un campo de formulario en Woocommerce

Tags: php, javascript, html5, wordpress, woocommerce

En el formulario de Checkout he creado un campo select.  Mi duda es como en Wordpress o Woocmmerce este camppo se puede dejar como obligatorio.

```
    <p class="form-row form-row-wide validate-required validate-region" id="shipping_region_field" data-priority="6">

      <select name="shipping_region" id="shipping_region" class="state_select select2-selection--single" autocomplete="address-level1" data-placeholder="" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
            <option>Opción 01</option>
            <option>Opción 02</option>
      </select>
    </p>
```

Comment: Ya intentaste utilizar el atributo `required` ?